# Joining a table on itself

Tags: sql, join

Is there a better way to write this SQL query?

```
SELECT *,  (SELECT TOP 1 columnB FROM mytable WHERE mytable.columnC = T1.columnC ORDER BY columnD) as firstRecordOfColumnB
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE columnA = 'apple') as T1
```

Notice that columnC is not the primary key.

Comment: Your join condition isn't doing anything useful since it's the same field in the same table, unless it's a non-unique column, then you're just basically picking a random row to return.  Are you sure this is what you mean?

Comment: it was my mistake to name it the keyColumn.
I have a table with many records with the same value for columnC.
I want to return a specific row plus some columns from the first record with with the same value for columnC.

Comment: There is not 'first' record as long as you do not define an order by. What is exactly the idea behind getting that 'first' record? What is it needed for?

Comment: Ok. i edited the query to have an order by.

i'm interested in the data stored in the first row of the set of rows that have the same value for columnC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the keyColumns is really a key column (i.e. unique), than the query can definitly be written more elegantly and efficiently...

```
SELECT
  *, columnB
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  columnA = 'apple'
```

Comment: columnB will be a part of * I guess? If you don't want columnB to be at the end you can simply write: *

Comment: no sorry, it was a mistake to name it keyColumn. it is not the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

This might be better in case of performance:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (TOP 1 myLookupTable.columnB FROM mytable AS myLookupTable WHERE myLookupTable.keyColumn = mytable.keyColumn) as firstRecordOfColumnB
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  columnA = 'apple'
```

But for the TOP 1 part I don't know any better solution.

**Edit:**
If the keyColumn is unique, the data in firstRecordOfColumnB would be the same as in mytable.columnB.
If it's not unique at least you need to sort that data to get a relevant TOP 1, example:

```
SELECT
  *,
  (TOP 1 myLookupTable.columnB FROM mytable AS myLookupTable WHERE myLookupTable.keyColumn = mytable.keyColumn
   ORDER BY myLookupTable.sortColumn) as firstRecordOfColumnB
FROM
  mytable
WHERE
  columnA = 'apple'
```

Comment: thx. i didn't know that i can use AS like this:
SELECT ... FROM mytable AS myLookupTable ...
and yes, i'm not joining on the primary key. but the table is already sorted.

Comment: You are welcome. Please mark this as the answer if you think it solved your problem :)